# How to dynamically assign values to a PreparedStatement?

Tags: java, sql, prepared-statement

Current Scenario:

```
String query= "select emp_role from emp where emp_id = ?";
String query= "select address.phone_no from address, emp where address.address_id=emp.address_id and emp.emp_id = ?";

PreparedStatement prepatedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
prepatedStatement.setInt(1, empId);
ResultSet rs = prepatedStatement.executeQuery();
```

Expected Scenario:

When I have queries with multiple inputs like the ones mentioned below

```
String query= "select emp_role from emp where emp_id = ? and emp_plan = ?";
String query= "select emp_id,emp_name from (select emp_id,emp_name from emp_1 where emp_1_id = ?)union(select emp_id,emp_name from emp_2 where emp_2_id = ?)";
```

I need to have a generic prepatedStatement logic to do this.

Take a look at - [How to create a prepared statement dynamically - and re-use the query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18466437/how-to-create-a-prepared-statement-dynamically-and-re-use-the-query)

This logic works fine but I still have to set values to map explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

There is no automatic way of doing the things but you could improve it with something like:

```
List<String> empParameters = getMeParameters();//may be factory here?
ResultSet rs = getResultSet(.....);
......
private ResultSet getResultSet(PreparedStatement prepatedStatement,   List<String> empParameters) {
     int i = 0;
     for (String empParameter : empParameters) {
         prepatedStatement.setInt(i++, empParameter);
     }
     return prepatedStatement.executeQuery();
}
```